Conky graph to linear graph using standard tools
Ubuntu 22.04, Conky 1.12.2
When I use ${cpugraph cpu0}, ${diskiograph} and other variables, the graph is displayed as a bar filled with color or gradient
graph bar
Is it possible to make the graph as a line?
graph lineal
Without using lua. That is, using standard means of the conky.text section.

There is no mention of Ubuntu in your question or any info that you have tried to do this in any way yourself already.  Please add the missing info.

I've added the version of Ubuntu and conky I'm using. I haven't done anything because I don't know what to do. I just added the variable ${cpugraph cpu0} and saw a graph that I didn't really like the look of. So I decided to argue here. I have been using linux for 2 months. So there are a lot of things I don't know.
